# Using an AC plug for DC current

Tags: ac, dc, plug

If I have a plug that is rated 10A @ 250V AC, is it safe to assume I can use it at 10A @ 12V DC? Could it be used at higher current or should its maximum be lower for that matter?

Thanks!

Comment: Connor Wolf says that, at relatively low frequencies and currents (like yours), [amps are amps are amps](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/45679/49251).

Comment: You can use it at 10A, but ensure both pieces are visibly marked to avoid any possible accidents.

Answer (score 2):

If it's rated at 10A you can't go higher than that safely. The amp rating should be based upon the amount that the contact resistance will cause the plug to heat up. If the current is higher than this, regardless of the voltage being supplied, the contacts may start heating up too much causing issues.

Generally speaking for plugs, the voltage and amp ratings are for different things. The voltage rating is for preventing shorting from happening do to dielectric breakdown. The current is for determining how much heat can be generated within the device.

If it was me, and I wanted to be safe, I would stay under 10A even at 12V DC.

Answer (score 1):

It will probably be fine at 10A, 12V DC, especially if you don't connect/disconnect it under load.

Some switches and connectors are rated at a lower current and/or voltage when operating at DC than at AC, see e.g. the 2nd page of [this datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/307/D2F_1110-6257.pdf) for a general-purpose microswitch.  This is because when the switch is opened under load (or the plug is unplugged), an arc will form between the contacts that must be extinguished.  An AC arc extinguishes more easily than a DC arc because the current passes through zero periodically.

Comment: DC is also more troublesome because you can have a reactive load and not know it until you pull the plug.